# MVC 4 binding to List for child table

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a `Product` model created and would like to add relevant taxes for the product from a `Tax` model. A single product can have multiple taxes applied so I have created another model `TaxApplied` to store relations.

I have added a `ListBox` with `MultiSelectList` to the Create view for `Product` which shows the available taxes.

```
 @Html.ListBox("AppliedTaxes", ViewBag.AppliedTaxes as MultiSelectList)
```

But I get the following error when I try to create a product with selected Taxes. How should I modify the view,model or controller such as to add the tax relations as well?

```
The ViewData item that has the key 'AppliedTaxes' is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[StoreManager.Models.TaxApplied, StoreManager, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'.
```

Models Described below

```
public class Product
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; 
        public float SalePrice { get; set; }
        public List<TaxApplied> AppliedTaxes { get; set; }

    }        

public class Tax
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Tax Code")]
        public string TaxCode { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Tax Percent")]
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }

    public class TaxApplied
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Product")]
        public int ProductID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Tax")]
        public int TaxID { get; set; }

        public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
        public virtual Tax Tax { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller actions for `Product` create

```
//
// GET: /Product/Create

public ActionResult Create()
{
    ViewBag.NavProduct = "active";

    MultiSelectList taxes = new MultiSelectList(db.Taxes.ToList<Tax>(), "ID", "Name");
    ViewBag.AppliedTaxes = taxes;

    return View();
}

//
// POST: /Product/Create

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(Product product)
{
    ViewBag.NavProduct = "active";
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Products.Add(product);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

        return View(product);
 }
```

Comment: Have a look at the variable types for Html.ListBox. It expects a List<SelectListItem> and you seem to be passing it List<AppliedTaxes>.  Try Html.ListBox("AppliedTaxes, new SelectList((IList<AppliedTaxes>)ViewBag.Taxes, ...))

Comment: I have modified the controller for the view. The form shows up just fine. It's the form submit that gives me the error
MultiSelectList taxes = new MultiSelectList(db.Taxes.ToList<Tax>(), "ID", "Name");
            ViewBag.AppliedTaxes = taxes;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return a `MultiSelectList` from your generic list.

Here is an example of how to do it:

```
var appliedTaxes = new List<TaxApplied>();
appliedTaxes.Add(new TaxApplied { ID = 1, ProductID = 1 });
var items = appliedTaxes.Select(t => new SelectListItem { Text = t.ID.ToString(), Value = t.ProductID.ToString() }).ToList();
ViewBag.AppliedTaxes = new MultiSelectList(items, "Text", "Value");
```

Please note I am only using the Id's as the text and value for demonstration purposes.

**Update**

Change your post to this:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(Product product)
{
    ViewBag.NavProduct = "active";
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Products.Add(product);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    MultiSelectList taxes = new MultiSelectList(db.Taxes.ToList<Tax>(), "ID", "Name");
    ViewBag.AppliedTaxes = taxes;

    return View()
}
```

Comment: The views show up fine. I have the exact controller action in place. Its the form submit that gives me the error

Comment: Sorry, you need to return the same code above from your post method too. I would add your post controller action method to the answer to update it, just in case people misunderstand like me.

Comment: I've updated with the fix now, you just need to return the collection as you do with the httpget. :)

Comment: I did and the error has disappeared, but the page just return back to the form. No product is added. The POST action isn't being executed. Is my logic for a parent and child table correct in the MVC 4 context?

Comment: Sorry, the POST action is being executed but the ModelState gives an invalid causing the product add to fail